# Excel VBA Looping Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

VBA newbie here. I am struggling with writing a script to pull data from specific cells in multiple (~250) worksheets into a master worksheet. Example:
I want the script to pull data from cells B3:C3, E4, B15:C20 in the worksheet titled Cand 4, Cand 5, Cand 6, etc.

I think I've got the looping portion working correctly, but am missing something else. Help!
Anyone have a guess at what the script would look like? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52410421/edit) your question with the looping portion, and it'll probably be clearer what else you're missing.

Comment: If you post the code you already have, it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

1. Create a new sheet (lets call it Back_End).
2. In this sheet, create a named range (ctrl-F3) of all the sheet names whose data you want to paste. Lets call it "Sheets_List"
3. Copy paste the data using the code (seen below)

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste_Sheets()

Dim i
Dim Sheet_List As Range
Dim Sheet_List_String As String

For i = 1 To 250 'number of sheets

Set Sheet_List = Range("Sheets_List")
Sheet_List_String = Sheet_List.Cells(i, 1)

'Range 1
Sheets(Sheet_List_String).Range("B3:C3").Copy Sheets("Master").Cells(i,1) 'Destination 1 (i=row, 1=column)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Range 2
Sheets(Sheet_List_String).Range("E4").Copy Sheets("Master").Cells(i,1) 'Destination 2 (i=row, 1=column)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Range 3
Sheets(Sheet_List_String).Range("B15:C20").Copy Sheets("Master").Cells(i,1) 'Destination 3 (i=row, 1=column)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have made the change. You can change the 'i' and '1' to the desired destinations.

Comment: Are you able to not use all the  select 's in your code?

Comment: For example, this one line would take care of 7 lines of your code.  `Sheets(Sheet_List_String).Range("B3:C3").Copy Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 1)`